# How to delete old product image while importing new ones

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

During an large product import i managed to upload the wrong low-res images, and I need to replace these with new ones. If I re-import only the images, the old images will still be present and visible in the catalog. Is there a way to remove or hide the wrong images during import?

Comment: Are you adding image from CSV or programetically?

Comment: By importing CSV